# Matlab: create objects with source information

Tags: matlab

I am loading a file ...

```
obj = load('foo1.txt');
% obj is a double array of size (NY,NX)
```

However, there are many such files and I wish to parse then save them in an array

```
asdf = zeros(1, numObjs);
for index = 1:numObjs
    obj = load(sprintf(foo%d.txt,index));
    asdf(index) = obj;
end
```

In this case, the procedure fails since the number of objects in asdf(i), namely the size of i ... which is one ~= the size of obj ... sizeof(obj).

I tried fooling around with a struct, but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is about trying to put arrays inside of arrays, but the Title is about objects and source information?  I don't see how the title is related to the question.

Comment: So no answer because the title is bad?

Comment: No, no answer yet because I'm working on the answer.  I thought that I'd take a minute first to try to give you some friendly advice, since this is your first StackOverflow post.

Comment: ... and now nkjt has already posted pretty much what I was going to :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cell array instead:

```
asdf{numObjs} = [];  % intialises; does not preallocate memory for cell contents

for index = 1:numObjs
    asdf{index} = load(sprintf(foo%d.txt,index));
end
```